# What is "-fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found"?

Tags: gcc, debian

I got following error message when I run gcc or dmd compiler.

```
gcc: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin.so not found
```

I've never configured such linker settings. I'm using `gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)`

Comment: I am also facing same problem. Although I have included all the paths where it exists at my system. Not sure how the mips64-nlm-linux-g++ looking for it ?